# Spring-Boot Tomcat Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

Where are the Embedded Tomcat configuration files for spring-boot-starter-web? I want to set autoDeploy="true" to make the Embedded Tomcat hot deploy changes to my html files.

Comment: are you using maven in your project to download the depnedencies?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-tomcat

Comment: I suppose changing html files doesn't require autoDeploy

Comment: @hsluo - HTML files require a redeploy w/ the embedded container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An embedded container has no notion of an autoDeploy (that's a container feature that applies to deployed war files). If you just want to reload static resources at dev time, the docs are here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-hotswapping

Comment: Hi Dave, Our spring-boot app (web) consumes static contents (.html, .jsp, images, .css etc.) that is a mounted path from an external. We noticed that our spring-boot app reflects ONLY when there is a NEW jsp file or other static files dropping in that mounted directory, we can see the change from browser. However, if a static file is UPDATED, browser does not reflect until we restart the app.  Besides using `spring-boot-devtools` for PROD, is there a way to configure it without restarting? We use embedded tomcat,  configured `server.tomcat.context.preresources.base=/external/contents/` Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `spring.resources.static-locations=file:///path/to/external/contents`? (I don't think `server.tomcat.context.preresources.base` does anything at all in a vanilla Spring Boot app. Maybe you tweaked it?)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Let me try that. `spring.resources.static-locations=file:///path/to/external/contents`